# why does google analytics showing only 99999 results in Top Events reports?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

today , one of my ga profile showing only 99999 results in Top Events reports , not sure whether it's because one thing i did yesterday .

yesterday , i run google v4 api in R, by the package of googleanalyticsR,and getting quota error :

Quota Error: The number of recent failed writes is too high.

so , my questing is , if i can only get 99999 results in the profile from now on ?
many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Analytics Core Reporting API returns a maximum of 10,000 rows per request but you can use 'max-results' parameter to specify the maximum number of rows to include in the response in combination with 'start-index' to retrieve a subset of elements:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#maxResults

Comment: To make this a little clearer, the API will never return more than ten thousand rows per query - default is one thousand max, and you can use maxResults to set this to a different (smaller or larger) value, but never to more than 10,000.

Comment: Great! Can you marks the answer as correct, please?

Comment: But to be clear `googleAnalyticsR` will page through all the results if you set the `max=-1`, so you can get a lot more than 10000 results, if you use the 50,000 API calls per day the theoretical maximum is 50million rows.